# How to find or reset Postgresql psql postgres user password?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to get into my postgres shell to manage my database and I am running into an issue getting into my postgres shell.

```
omars-mbp:postgres omarjandali$ brew services restart postgres
Stopping `postgresql`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
omars-mbp:postgres omarjandali$ psql
Password for user omarjandali: 
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "omarjandali"
```

I also tried the default psql postgres user:

```
omars-mbp:postgres omarjandali$ psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
omars-mbp:postgres omarjandali$
```

Is there a way for me to reset the password. I don't remember setting a master password.

Comment: Hi, if my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1.** Backup the pg_hba.conf file by copying it to a different location or just rename it to pg_hba.conf.bk

**Step 2.** Edit the pg_dba.conf file and change all local connections from md5 to trust. By doing this, you can log in to the PostgreSQL database server without using a password.

**Step 3.** Restart the PostgreSQL server (Service).

**Step 4.** Connect to PostgreSQL database server using any tool such as psql or pgAdmin:

```
psql -U postgres
```

PostgreSQL will not require a password to login.

**Step 5.** Execute the following command to set a new password for the postgres user.

`ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';`

Courtesy of [PostgreSQLTutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-reset-password/)